# IBM Informix aggregate function

Tags: sql, database, function, informix

I need to develop some kind of function in a informix db, in order to split one string into multiple rows for example:

```
     Column1
one,two,three,four
```

And my expected result is:

```
column1
 one
 two
 three
 four
```

What i was thinking is to create a function, that splits the string into multiple rows. My actual code is the next one :

```
create  function split(text_splitted varchar(100), separator char(1))
returning varchar(100)

define splitted_word varchar(100);
define current_val char(1);
define start, cont integer;

let start = 0;
let splitted_word = "";
let current_val = "";

for cont = 0 to  length(text_splitted)
      let current_val = substr(text_splitted, cont, 1);

  if current_val =  separator then
      let splitted_word = substr(text_splitted, start, cont - start);
      let start = cont + 1;

      return splitted_word with resume;
    end if;
end for;
end function
```

If you execute the next statement, works find:

```
execute function split('hello.my.name.is', '.');
```

And the result is:

```
hello
my
name
```

this is perfect, but my problem is that when you launch a query with this function, and the function returns more than one row an error is raised. What i have been google, is that i need to create an aggregate function but i am not able to build this function. I am new in this kind of developing....

Here is the little documentation i found: http://www.pacs.tju.edu/informix/answers/english/docs/dbdk/is40/extend/04aggs3.html

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to want/need a "disaggregate" rather than an "aggregate". You're trying to generate multiple rows from a single value, whereas an aggregate generates a single value from multiple rows. Can you show a query where you'd like to use it, and show some sample data (a couple of rows for the input would be enough) and the corresponding desired output? There may be ways to do it with `FROM TABLE(EXECUTE FUNCTION split(...))` or some such notation, but I'm worried about how that would work with different rows in the input data — how would it be made into a "correlated sub-query" or whatever.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan A simple example for this is the next one:` SELECT split(description, '.') FROM product ` and the result of this query will appear several rows, with the description of each product of my table. This description table has many comment types, separate with some kind of separators. My need, is for each product description is as you suggest, "disaggregate" the rows into many rows. an example for the product description query is: normal result for one product in one line`14cm - bottle - Garden Store` and the result i wanna get is: `1ºrow:  14cm. 2ºrow: bottle. 3ºrow: Garden Store`